# Convert string with "_" to int?

Tags: python

I have a function which takes a string input, tries to convert it to integer and then proceeds with two alternative paths depending on whether the conversion succeeded or not:

```
def make_int(arg):
    try:
       int_value = int(arg)
    except ValueError:
       str_value = arg
```

I now was quite surprised when the string `'123_2307_7'` was happily converted to the integer `12323077` - whereas I was expecting it to follow the `str` path here. What details of `str -> int` conversion is it I have not yet grokked?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)? _"Optionally, the string can ... have single underscores interspersed between digits."_ (Since Python 3.6, to reflect the fact that the same thing is allowed in numeric literals.)

Comment: This `10_000` is now conventionally correct number

Comment: I want to know what groke means (apart from the obscure Scottish terminology which doesn't seem to fit this context)

Comment: `int` accepts valid integer literals, in which `_` are simply ignored.

Comment: @Pingu "Grok" is a "made-up" word from one(?) of Heinlein's novels that has entered the English lexicon; it basically means "understand completely or deeply".

Comment: @chepner I wasn't being too serious. However, worth mentioning that the spelling has been altered since I wrote that comment

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @jonrsharpe the docs says you can embed single `_` charcaters in your integer literal - which are simply ignored. Closing.

Answer (score -1):

In python you can write any integer/float this way :
XXX_XXX_XXX

Keep in mind that integer/float are objects in python.

Comment: Thank you for your second sentence. Perhaps you could explain its relevance

Comment: It was the "are objects" which I failed to take into account in my first attempt at reading the documentation.